# This is... to me! (Matches Puzzle)

Tags: visual, lateral-thinking, matches

Make these two *"equivalent"* equations true by simply moving (changing the position of) **exactly** three lines (per equation). The equations are two different representations of the same (what I mean by this is up to you to figure out). No inequalities(≠, >, < or ≤) are allowed. Also, no rotation of the image needed.

---

[image]

[image]

---

**EDIT:** To minimize potential answers, I'm going to tell you that one equation contains letters only. Remember what I said earlier -  *"The equations are two different representations of the same (what I mean by this is up to you to figure out)"*. Also, the title will hopefully make sense once you figure out the correct answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can move 3 matchsticks per statement to obtain the following two statements,

> [image: first statement: Π = PI, second statement: Π = 3.14]

where one of the matchsticks in the second statement has been stood up on its end to create a dot. The first statement contains only letters, and
the statements are different representations of

> the Greek letter π, hence the title: "This is [Greek to me](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_to_me)!"

Comment: I thought the title was referencing rot13(rnfl nf cvr), but yours is better

Comment: This is the intended answer, well done!

Comment: As a pedantic mathematician, I will note that the second equation is not true.  :/

Comment: @XanderHenderson Agreed, this is why I refrained from calling it such in my answer. \:

Answer (score 14):

I think, ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

> [image: my-solution-to-matchstick-puzzle]

Comment: It's a good answer, but not the intended one

Comment: This was the answer I came up with, and has the advantage (over the accepted answer) of being mathematically correct. :D

Answer (score 1):

> The ones in the second aren't identical, but still: 
> [image]

Comment: Nice attempt, but I mean't that the two equations are equivalent *to each other*. I'll edit to clarify this.

Comment: @Prim3numbah: If one doesn't mind uneven horizontal spacing, I think "0=0" and "0=00" could be formed via three moves in each case.